# Как сохранить данные после выхода из приложения Jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose

Всем привет,в общем я даже не могу себя назвать разработчиком,но стараюсь им стать.Изучаю jetpack compose ,хочу создать простой кликер.У меня возникла проблема с сохранением/восстановлением данных.
В данный момент мне всего лишь нужно хранить значение счетчика,даже после выхода пользователем из приложения.То,что представлено ниже,не работает.Оно работает только при сворачивании приложения и изменения положения экрана.Много ютуба перерыл ,но подходящего решения не нашел.Спасибо всем,кто поможет.

```
data class Counter (var testCount: Int)
    val counterSaver = run {
        val counterKey = "counter"
        mapSaver(
            save = {
                mapOf(counterKey to it.testCount)
            } ,
            restore = {
                Counter (it[counterKey] as Int)
            }
        )
    }
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Hometest(
    navController: NavController ,
) {
    var countInt by rememberSaveable (stateSaver = counterSaver){ mutableStateOf(Counter(0)) }
etc... }
```

Comment: ну rememberSaveable всего лишь заменяет собой bundle, а значит для постоянного хранения те же правила - preferences, база данных, файлы...

Comment: С приходом Compose ничего в этом разрезе не изменилось, все старые методы постоянного хранения все так же актуальны. Для одного счетчика SharedPreferences вполне подойдет. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences